# VB Xor - double-encryption

Tags: vb.net, encryption, vb6, xor

I am coding in VB6, but I can rewrite it for VB.net if it would help.

I am using XOR to do some basic encryption: printa = printa + Chr((q Xor chCode))

I am converting the result back to characters. The problem comes when I double encrypt. I think the problem arises when a XOR operation resulting in a 0. Hence, Chr(0) = a null character. PS: the chCode can be anything 1 to 254. Also when I double encrypt the source text is often out side the range of printable characters.

Any help would be appreciated. I'll try to give more info if needed. Thx

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not encryption. Anyway, here's a great introduction: [Walkthrough: Encrypting and Decrypting Strings in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172831.aspx)

Comment: you may want to use chr$()

Answer (score 0):

Encryption is an operation that works on all bits of the message and the result is no longer within the printable area, as you state.

There is no inherent problem with handling such a string internally in VB though, since it stores the string length at the beginning of the string, rather than using null-termination like in C.

You should look at base64-encoding your encrypted message to get back to the printable range if that is what you need. What that does is basically using 4 bytes to represent 6 bits from 3 bytes each.